# AlwaysOn listeners across subnets

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, listener

Can someone help me clear something up with regards to AlwaysOn listeners across 2 subnets.
Windows Server 2019
SQL Server 2019
This is in Azure

I have created a multi-subnet AG.
The listener has 2 IP addresses, one from each region/subnet.

Is it normal that pinging the listener may always time out even when the ping resolves to the IP address that is currently online?
Ping replies though when pinging from the the primary itself but anywhere outside of this server does not reply
What I'm getting at is that ping is not a reliable tool to confirm connectivity to an AlwaysOn listener.

Regarding connecting to the listener.
I have read about the cluster settings **RegisterAllprovidersIP** & **HostRecordTTL** for troubleshooting intermittent disconnects.
If the client supports MULTISUBNETFAILOVER - Is it safe to say that these settings don't matter?
I would think that we only tinker with those settings if the client does not have the option for MULTISUBNETFAILOVER

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ping is not a reliable tool to confirm connectivity to an AlwaysOn listener.

Correct.  DNS will return two IPs for the hostname, and you have no control over which one Ping uses.  And ping uses different ports and protocols than TDS, which uses TCP and port 1433 by default.

To test first run `nslookup` to see the IP addresses, then use test-netconnection to test the IPs.  Only one should succeed.

`test-netconnection xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port 1433`

> I would think that we only tinker with those settings if the client does not have the option for MULTISUBNETFAILOVER

Correct.

Comment: Thank you very much - Appreciated

Comment: Does changing the values for  RegisterAllprovidersIP & HostRecordTTL change the behavior of clients that does have MULTISUBNETFAILOVER?

Comment: Changing RegisterAllprovidersIP causes DNS to send only one IP (of the current primary) to the client.